# How do I set the Cache-Control header on ASP.NET Forms Authentication redirect?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, caching, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET application that uses standard forms authentication.  Imagine the following scenario

1. User (NOT authenticated) requests http://myapp.com/Foo (which requires user to be authenticated)
2. Response:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Location: /Login?ReturnUrl=%2fFoo
   (rest of response headers and body omitted...)
   ```
3. User logs in.
4. (Later) User (authenticated) requests http://myapp.com/Foo

At this point, I have observed that sometimes Chrome will have cached the redirect and the login page, and therefore show the login page to the already-logged-in user without sending a request to the server.  It doesn't seem to happen if the Chrome developer tools are open (so I could definitively prove it), but it would explain what I have observed and can piece together from IIS logs, etc.

I believe I can stop Chrome from doing this by including a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header in the 302 redirect response.  Can I make the Forms Auth module do this?